# Add hyphen symbol in json object creation in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I am trying to add hyphen to json creation it shows error as;

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
student-ids : [{
```

My JSON is like this:

```
var testJson = {
student-ids : [{
student-id : "123"},{
student-id : "21321"},{
student-id : "123"},{
student-id : "21321"
}]
};
console.log(testJson)
```

Comment: Where and how you are adding the hypen in your code.

Comment: As an aside, what you're doing there isn't JSON, it's an object. [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the property names that contain dashes:

```
"student-id" : "123"
```

You may want to use an underscore instead:

```
student_id : "123"
```

Or camel case:

```
studentId : "123"
```

Otherwise, you'll have to access the property with the bracket notation `foo['student-id']`, which doesn't look as nice as `foo.studentId`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var testJson = {
   "student-ids" : [{
   "student-id" : "123"},{
"student-id" : "21321"},{
"student-id" : "123"},{
"student-id" : "21321"
}]
};
console.log(testJson)
```